# $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] is not triggered when form is posted for the first time on Android Chrome browsers

Tags: php, html, forms, form-submit

I have been trying to process the inputs of a web form which submits to itself. Everything works fine except for chrome android browser. The code works well when accessed through browsers on PC and other mobile browsers like UC Browser. But miserably fails in chrome android. The submit button and "post" requests are not set on the first run. And more strangely the same code works on same chrome browser when reloaded. help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the code supposed to catch the values submitted

```
?php
require_once('connect_db.php');
require_once('functions.php');

$timezone = "Asia/Kolkata";
date_default_timezone_set($timezone);



if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {


$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['name']);
$gender = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['gender']);
$dob = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['dob']);
// And Some more Variables managed here


}
?>
```

And here is the html form part

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" data-toggle="validator">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="name" class="control-label">Name:</label>
<input class="form-control" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" autofocus="autofocus" id="name" placeholder="Name" data-error="Enter Your Name" name="name" required="" type="text"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group w3ls-opt">
<label for="Gender" class="control-label">Gender</label> <label class="w3layouts"> <input name="gender" id="gender1" value="male" checked="checked" type="radio">Male
</label> <label class="w3layouts label2"> <input name="gender" id="gender2" value="female" type="radio">Female </label> <label class="w3layouts"> <input name="gender" id="gender3" value="other" type="radio">Other
</label> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="dob" class="control-label">Date of Birth</label>
<input class="form-control" id="dob" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="dob" required="" max="31/05/1995" data-error="Enter Your Date of Birth in dd/mm/yyyy format" type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="inputEmail" class="control-label">Email:</label> <input class="form-control" style="text-transform:lowercase" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" data-error="Enter a valid Email" name="email" required="" type="email"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="parent" class="control-label">Name
of Father/Parent/Guardian/Husband</label> <input class="form-control" id="father" placeholder="Name of Father" name="father" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" required="" data-error="Enter Your Parent's Name" type="text">
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="mother" class="control-label">Name
of Mother</label> <input class="form-control" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" id="mother" placeholder="Name of Mother" name="mother" required="" data-error="Enter Your Mother's Name" type="text"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="address1">Address</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="address1" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" name="address1" data-error="Enter Address" required=""></textarea>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <label class="control-label" for="address2">Address</label>
<textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="address2" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" name="address2" data-error="Enter Address" required="" readonly="readonly">
OTTATHARA
KODUP PO
PIN:676504</textarea> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="Phone" class="control-label">Phone:</label> <input class="form-control" name="phone" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone" data-error="Enter a valid Phone Number" required="" min="0000000000" max="99999999999" type="number"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="address">Course
Presently Studying</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" id="course" name="course" required="">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="hsc">+2</option>
<option value="vhsc">VHSC</option>
<option value="diploma">Diploma</option>
<option value="graduation">Graduation</option>
<option value="professional">Professional Degree</option>
<option value="bed">B.Ed</option>
<option value="pg">Postgraduation</option>
<option value="mphil">M Phil</option>
<option value="research">Research</option>
<option value="certificate">Certificate Course</option>
<option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="course_details" class="control-label">Deatils of Course(Group/Main/Branch):</label> <input class="form-control" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" placeholder="Course Details" name="course_details" id="course_details" required="" type="text"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors" required=""></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="institution" class="control-label">Name of Institution:</label> <input class="form-control" onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" id="institution" placeholder="Institution" name="institution" required="" type="text"> 
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="duration_year">Course Duration(Year)</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" id="duration_year" name="duration_year">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="duration_year">Course Duration(Month)</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" id="duration_month" name="duration_month">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="0">0</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="financial status">Financial Status</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" id="finance" name="finance">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="apl">APL</option>
<option value="bpl">BPL</option>
<option value="finance_not_say">Prefer not to Specify</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="if_working">Are you Working Now?</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" id="if_working" name="if_working" required="" onchange="change_work_option(this)">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
<option value="no">No</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label" for="working_type">If working, details of employment</label>&nbsp;
<select class="form-control" id="working_type" name="working_type" disabled>
<option value="select" selected="selected">Select</option>
<option value="government">Government</option>
<option value="private">Private</option>
<option value="self employed">Self Employed</option>
<option value="others">Others</option>
</select>
<div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> <label for="interest" class="control-label">Interests</label> <input onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" class="form-control" id="interests" placeholder="Interests" name="interest" type="text"> </div>
<div class="form-group"> <label for="aspiration" class="control-label">Career Aspirations</label> <input onfocusout="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase();" class="form-control" id="aspiration" placeholder="Aspiration" name="aspiration" type="text"> </div>
<div class="form-group">  <input class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id ="submit" name="submit" value="submit" type="submit">
</div>
</form>
```

Edited..

After posting above question I have been making a number of trail and errors and found that error is not with my form or code. Even so simple a form like given below fails. But when I reload it works..I read something about a bug in Chrome. Any solution or hack?

here is the simple form i tried in vain last

```
<html><body>

<?php echo $_POST["name"]." echoing"; ?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"  name="student_form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

<input type="text" name="name"  />
<input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
```

Comment: are you sure the form is actually being sent? Do you see a request fired in dev tools? What does `var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD;]);` tell you?

Comment: Please see my edited question. Form is being sent. But it contains no data var_dump gives NULL. But, as I said, it works, the second time..

Comment: I have never seen something lie this in the past. Maybe the network tab can give us more info? I get the feeling that the request is sent properly, but then is altered once it reaches the server.

Comment: what @WilliamPerron says... this is for sure not a chrome bug, otherwise half of the internet would've been collapsed by now. only thing what comes to mind (and what you might be refering to as a bug) is that it _could_ be that the first time the page is loaded from cache, when refreshing the cache is cleared. But afaik chrome is smart enough not to bluntly load a cached page when stuff is posted...

Comment: Actually when the cache is not cleared it works. As I clear the cache, to make sure it works for a user who loads it the first time, the page submits null values..

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your support. This is not exactly an answer to the cause of the issue, but simply how I managed to get out of it and set my form working. :)

As U guys pointed out, it should nt be a bug in chrome android( it could be more disastrous in that case). And when I tried many "deductive" debugging and trial and error I found something which may lead to clutch to the root of the error.
1. It works fine when I tested on another web host 
2. In my erroneous host cum browser, when the form is submitted the url returned  carries a strange get parameter Www.xxxx.com/?i=1

Since I had to solve the problem immediately, I manned a function in the controller file to reload the uri if the browser is android chrome and it is tab is "fresh" using

```
isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && 
($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']    === 'max-age=0' || $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] == 'no-cache')
```

and it worked. But would be glad to know any insights u could share